# Setting up Gradle for api 26 (Android)

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-support-library, android-8.0-oreo

Since I have upgraded my Nexus 5x to Android O DP3 I am not able to test my applications. I get the error for not having configured my Gradle-file to work with the new API-level (26).

So I changed this and the dependencies, but I keep getting errors on ALL my support libraries like

```
Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:26.0.0-beta2
```

Clicking on

```
Install repository and sync project
```

Pops up a progressdialog for downloading the right dependency but does not remove the error. Cleaning up project, installing repositories and then rebuilding the project won't work either.

#### appcompat-v7

On appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta2 I get (before even a Gradle sync) squickly lines with the error:

```
When using a compileSdkVersion older than android-O revision 2,
the support library version must be 26.0.0-alpha1 or lower (was 26.0.0-beta2)
```

Can someone help me get the gradle file to be configured correctly for Android API 26?
Any help would be appreciated.

PS: I'm using Gradle 3.0.0-alpha3 at the moment but get the same error on Gradle 2.3.2

My Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "********"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 3
    versionName "2.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.redbooth:WelcomeCoordinator:1.0.1'
compile 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-android:1.4.0'
compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
compile 'com.ramotion.foldingcell:folding-cell:1.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Refer to my answer here how I got it working https://stackoverflow.com/a/45706108/5268588

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Have you added the [google maven endpoint](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#26-0-0-beta1)?

> **Important:** The support libraries are now available through Google's Maven repository. You do not need to download the support repository from the SDK Manager. For more information, see [Support Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html#add-library).

Add the endpoint to your *build.gradle* file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}
```

Which can be replaced by the shortcut `google()` since Android Gradle v3:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

If you already have any maven url inside `repositories`, you can add the reference after them, i.e.:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is wrong, jcenter() is *before* maven tag

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me.
The specified url was jitpack.io

Comment: The error 
"When using a compileSdkVersion older than android-O revision 2,
the support library version must be 26.0.0-alpha1 or lower (was 26.0.0-beta2)"

Is still showing. But I'm able to build and run the app on my phone without problems, it seems..
Any thoughts?

Comment: @GunnarK you can add both urls placing them one after another, just like this: `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }`

Comment: @GunnarK I guess your Android Studio has not updated the latest sdk available (which right now is eventually 26.0.0-beta2). Maybe the update urls are cached due to a proxy or sth. If you go to _Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK_ you have three tabs. The last one `SDK Update Sites` check _Force https://... resources [...]_ try restarting

Comment: @I.G.Pascual Thank you for this clarification. I have set the maven repository to `repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }`
The red underline error on appcompat-v7 seems to only show itself in Android Studio 3.0 Canary. Checking Forced updates and restarting didn't do anything..
In AS 2.3.2 the error is not showing.
Probably a bug in Canary, since the building process for an app functions normally

Comment: @GunnarK I've installed AS 3.0, same happening here. I guess sth's missing in the version tables/xml... we won't worry about it

Comment: No fix on *When using a compileSdkVersion older than android-O revision 2,
the support library version must be 26.0.0-alpha1 or lower (was 26.0.0-beta2)*

Comment: is adding google() on repositories section is same as above?

Comment: @BaneeIshaqueK yes it is, but only since Android Gradle plugin v 3.0.0-alpha1 in Android Studio 3. I'd recomend waiting until Gradle plugin is in more stable mood :)

Comment: upgraded to alpha7, but layout designer is not working on alpha7 (already filed a bug, see it here [Layout Designer Not Working...](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63943042). Now, i downgraded to latest stable version, 2.3.3. is `google()` will work? i am using global gradle distribution, and my version is : 4.1-milestone-1. And what about `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha7` line in `build.gradle` file?

Comment: You are a legend! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 14):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.keshav.retroft2arrayinsidearrayexamplekeshav"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1'
```

Answer (score 8):

Appart from setting maven source url to your gradle, I would suggest to add both design and appcompat libraries.
Currently the latest version is 26.1.0

```
maven {
    url "https://maven.google.com"
}
```

...

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

Answer (score 7):

You could add `google()` to repositories block

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/raw/master/maven-repo'

        }
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        google()
    }
}
```

Comment: Only since [Android Gradle plugin v 3.0.0-alpha1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44691858/failed-to-resolve-com-android-support-design25-4-0#comment76668403_44691903), in Android Studio 3

Answer (score 6):

Appears to be resolved by Android Studio 3.0 Canary 4 and Gradle 3.0.0-alpha4.

Answer (score 5):

you must add in your ***MODULE-LEVEL*** build.gradle file with:

```
//module-level build.gradle file
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'

    }
}
```

see: [Google's Maven repository](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven)

I have observed that when I use Android Studio 2.3.3 I **MUST** add *repositories{maven{url 'https://maven.google.com'}}* in **MODULE-LEVEL** build.gradle. 
In the case of Android Studio 3.0.0 there is no need for the addition in module-level build.gradle. It is enough the addition in **project-level** build.gradle which has been referred to in the other posts here, namely:

```
//project-level build.gradle file
allprojects {
 repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 11-14-2017:** The solution, that I present, was valid when I did the post. Since then, there have been various updates (even with respect to the site I refer to), and I do not know if now is valid. For one month I did my work depending on the solution above, until I upgraded to Android Studio 3.0.0

Comment: What error did you see that prompted you to add the additional configuration at the module-level?

Comment: @jk7: As a example, I present the errors for some libraries: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0, Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1, Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0 etc

Comment: @billst Did you check you using the same versions and maintain consistency?