# Failed to resolve: com.android.support.design:25.4.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I added the following line to my build.gradle(Module:app):

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
```

But when executing Gradle I'm getting

```
Failed to resolve: com.android.support.design:25.4.0
```

I got that the support code from the android [support design library](https://developer.android.com/training/material/design-library.html#CreateFAB) and added it to a new project. I added it to the dependency section as such:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
}
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: install support for 25.4.0 in you manager....
and second thing u cant keep two different version for support libs for example you keep 
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 :-25.3.1
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0 :- 25.4.0
you cant keep like this all support libs are with same versions

Answer (score 186, accepted):

> **Important:** The support libraries are now available through Google's Maven repository. You do not need to download the support
>   repository from the SDK Manager. For more information, see [Support
>   Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html).

**Step 1:** Open the build.gradle file for your application.

**Step 2:** Make sure that the repositories section includes a maven section with the "https://maven.google.com" endpoint. For example:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 3:** Add the support library to the dependencies section. For example, to add the v4 core-utils library, add the following lines:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.4.0"
}
```

Comment: ```maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }```
can be replaced by `google()`

Comment: @Ultimecia I tried `google()` but it was not recognized

Comment: `google()` is recognized only by the Android Gradle plugin v 3.0.0-alpha1, that's compatible only with Android Studio 3.0 Preview. If you are required to stick to using the stable version of Android Studio, then I'd wait for the release of stable 3.0 before using the google() repository and support libraries v25.4.0 to maintain coherence. You can notice also that support lib v25.3.1 is the latest version suggested from v2.3.2 IDE, indeed.

Comment: It is still asking me to install it with the help of SDK Manager. See here http://imgur.com/a/iTIYV

Answer (score 20):

A more updated version of the answer of ["Bhavesh Patadiya"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44691903/878126) :

1. In your project build.gradle file, add `google()` into the `repositories` blocks:

   ```
   repositories {
       jcenter()
       google()
   }
   ```
2. Update the same file with a newer Gradle version:

   ```
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
   ```
3. If the above cause you new issues or the same issue, exit Android-Studio, and delete the "gradle" folder/s (maybe also ".gradle" folder) and the "build" folder and sub-folders, and then open Android-Studio again.

Comment: I did what you said and got this error: https://puu.sh/wryKA/41871bedca.png I exited android studio and deleted the gradle and build folder and still got the same error.

Comment: I was already working with the updated Gradle version. I get the same error as before, just adding in the google() line breaks the gradle

Comment: @BrandonLavigne That's odd. I had the opposite. Are you using Android Studio canary 4, like me?

Comment: Very interesting comment. I tried gradle `2.3.3` and it seems it does not contain the method `google()`. Gonna try to delete the folders you mentioned

Answer (score 5):

Always keep `appcompact` version and support lib versionssame, so change `com.android.support:design:25.4.0` to `com.android.support:design:25.3.1`

Answer (score 5):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Mr. Bhavesh Patadiya give us a good solution. However, I'd like to share something more, to make fix process more explicit.

There are two "build.gradle" files under the project directory. Their pathes are to be "Your-project-root-dir/build.gradle" and "Your-project-root-dir/app/build.gradle" respectively. When you see the error information in your android studio, and try to trace the file, you will probably open the second one.

You should add this statement in the first file ("Your-project-root-dir/build.gradle").

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

and add the statements in the second build.gradle ("Your-project-root-dir/app/build.gradle")

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.2"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the android support Repository in the SDK manager . Also the Design Library depends on the Support v4 and AppCompat Support Libraries.

Same version android support must be the same with others..

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'  <-- same
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.1'  <-- same
```

Answer (score 1):

after adding :

```
maven {
    url "https://maven.google.com"
}
```

make sure your Gradle sync is on ONLINE mode
you can check it from:

> Android studio -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment ->
>   Gradle -> Offline work (make sure this check box is not selected)

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when there is `andoridtestImplementation` is added in app.build.

Remove `testImplementation`,`androidTestImplementation` from the app.build, that solves this issue.

Comment: In my case I accidentally quit Android Studio. When I reopened and I started getting gradle failed error  "Failed to resolve: com.android.support" this error doesn't tell much to resolve. I was searching then I came to your comment. I commented test dependencies and sync again. It starts working again. Later I made sure test dependencies spellings what I see is that when I quit Android Studio, It changes the androidTest libraries with one of drawable resource file name in my project. This is a bug in Android Studio. 
Thanks @Gowthaman

Answer (score 0):

Above answers did't resolve anything for me.

- Tried syncing the project- **Failed**.
- Tried building the project -**Failed**

Problem found :

> Sdk Support Repository was corrupted

.

Fix:

> Go to the SDK manager, click the "SDK Tools" tab. If the check-mark
>   for "Support Repository" is selected, unselect it and click OK. This
>   will delete all of the files in the repository. Then recheck the
>   check-mark, click GO and reinstall the repository.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20676406)

Comment: @Thom How is this not answering the question?  He lists what the problem was and what fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for support. I understand the point @Thom says. Question does not support the answer may be but it depends on users who may find it difficult to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the issue, check the project settings for offline mode. if offline mode is on, then off and sync the project. That fixed my issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
There is no library by that name. There is com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0.

Failed to resolve com.android.support:support-compat:25.4.0
Failed to resolve com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.4.0

I am trying to include this library to my project by adding

compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.7'

so remove this line from gradle
my error just resolved
```