# Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:25.4.0;Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.4.0

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, dependencies, firebaseui

I'm learning Firebase and I've been stuck because of these following errors :

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:customtabs:25.4.0
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta1
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:25.4.0
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.4.0
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0
```

The dependencies in my app/build.gradle file are these:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    //Firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'    
}
```

and for my build.gradle file outside the app folder

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to ask if what is/are solution/s for these errors? 
I've Been searching the net about the solutions for these errors but can't find one that can solve my problem.

Comment: Clean-Rebuild-RUN

Comment: Download the newest version of the support repo. Clean, rebuild, run.

Comment: i've added this line to my dependencies  compile `"com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.4.0"` then Clean, Rebuild, Run but still the same @LunarWatcher

Comment: there are some thigns like the support repo you need to download with the SDK

Comment: So update the support repo in the SDK is what I am trying to say

Comment: Another question with same Issue. I hope this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44691858/failed-to-resolve-com-android-support-design25-4-0/44706107

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this line of code:

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

with

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
```

And this two lines to have the same version:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.1'
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem at my program, and I was able to solve it.
As per [available libraries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available_libraries) at Firebase webpage you should use latest real time database dependency line:
com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2

Comment: Thanks. I have solved the Issue by using all the latest available libraries at firebase. thank you.