# Libraries missing. "Install and Sync" not working

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I opened my project and it shows me some errors, I'm starting in the world of Android now, so I don't know how to do this. I press over the *install Repository and sync project* but this doesn't do anything.

This is all the versions that I have in my project.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mx.com.dtss.carritocompras"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

And these are the errors

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: probably is the exclude com.android.support

Comment: @BrunoFerreira what do you mean?

Comment: So you have the line exclude group com.androis.support so the gradle not use libs with the name com.android.support, probably is because of that that you have the errors

Comment: hmm let me check if can be that.

Comment: what you can try IF YOU HAVE INTERNET is delete a folder named `.gradle` in `/path_to_your_workspace/you_project_folder` and then restart android studio. I will download all the missing dependencies

Comment: @JasonKrs i try what you recommend me but that doesn't work

Comment: @BrunoFerreira That's only excluded from the test code

Comment: You seem to need to setup the SDK manager and install the support library

Comment: i have read a question similar like mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44691858/failed-to-resolve-com-android-support-design25-4-0 but i can't solve mine haha

Comment: Yes, so, in the **other** `build.gradle` file, do you have code like that?

Comment: @cricket_007 idon't know what you mean with "other build gradle"

Comment: Your screenshot of code is from a `app/build.gradle` file. There is another one. Please [edit] your question with the text, not an image

Answer (score 0):

first option is to click on Install Repository and sync project,
if that dosent work then you need to add the repository from the dependencies manually, go to File > Project Structure > Dependencies 
click on + > Library dependency 
and search for the missing repository 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPutU.png)

Comment: i do what you told me but this doesn't fix the problem, i start a new project and when start (didn't move anything) fail in the same things, i've the last version of android studio

Comment: then something is wrong with your project, did you try closing it and opening again?
try updating android studio , here is a gradle similar to yours try comparing and removing part and see if it works

Comment: android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.claudiaedelman.shecodes.lecture.screenactivationreceiver"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

Comment: dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'})
   compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'}