# Sync failed after FirebaseUI dependency added

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

In `build.gradle`(app) dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
```

> This is the line that causes failure (without this line, it syncs without any problems)

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.1.1'
```

Error messages:

```
Failed to resolve: com.android.support:customtabs:25.4.0
Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta1
Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:25.4.0
Failed to resolve: com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0
```

Comment: See this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44691858/4815718

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to use this guide for solving `firebase-ui-auth` dependency error: [Firebase UI Auth](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth#configuration)

Secondly, for solving dependency error with `com.android.support:` in your project,

Go to project level **build.gradle** & check if it looks exactly like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works. I've added the `maven` many times but it wasn't working because I added in `buildscript`not in `allprojects`. #Life