# Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:27.+

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mypc.pop_up"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.+'
}
```

Comment: Does the support libraries download in your SDK?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html

Comment: take a look :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44691858/failed-to-resolve-com-android-support-design25-4-0

Answer (score 1):

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.your.package"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

dependencies {
   final SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION = '27.0.1'
   compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
   androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
   compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
}
```

Hi you should use like this

Answer (score 0):

> **Important:** The support libraries are now available through Google's Maven repository. You do not need to download the support
>   repository from the SDK Manager. For more information, see [Support
>   Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html).

**Step 1:** Open the build.gradle file for your application.

**Step 2:** Make sure that the repositories section includes a maven section with the "https://maven.google.com" endpoint. For example:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```