# Failed to resolve: com.android.support: design-v7:25.3.1

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

This is for my school project. I've got 1 error from my code;

Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design-v7:25.3.1

I've been done these things:
a. Configure my project structure into 25.
b. Added compile 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1' on my dependencies gradle.
C. update my another gradle with this code
d. Download Android API 25 on my SDK manager

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

And, I still got that error message.

This is my full code for build.gridle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.lenovo.home"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner     "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-   core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

this is my error message:
[image: this is my error message]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This might help... --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44691858/failed-to-resolve-com-android-support-design25-4-0

Comment: @JayDangarI've done all those things (as I said before in my question) but sill got the same error message :')

Comment: can you add all the error in your questions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

Instead of

```
compile 'com.android.support:design-v7:25.3.1'
```

> AS

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.lenovo.home"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner     "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    }
     }

    dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-   core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
   })
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
```

Comment: it ends up with 19 errors after build :') I used v7 for my application :)

Comment: Gradle issue must resolve after this. v7 is only or appCompat... not for design.