# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0 android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

i try to add recyclerview to my project and get this error appear and i added it from android studio dependencies
[image: this is error appear when try to add recyclerview in android studio]

[image: this is the compiled version ...]

Comment: change your dependency


compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1 android"
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1 android"

Comment: Click on Link . Install them

Comment: Starting from version 26 of support libraries, you should add to your buildscript dependencies `maven { url https://maven.google.com }`, read [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html#add-library)

Comment: thanks all it's worked with me fine and i post the solution under question

Comment: @ahmedkhattab Could you please highlight your solution? What did you add to resolve the issue after upgrading to support library 26?

Comment: see my answer in: [Setting up Gradle for api 26 (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46467737/4866544)

Comment: For Android Studio 2.3.3  you must add in your **MODULE-LEVEL** build.gradle file the following: `repositories { maven { url 'maven.google.com'; } }`. It is not enough the similar addition in the **project-level** build.gradle. See my answer to a similar question:[http://stackoverflow.com/a/46467737/4866544](http://stackoverflow.com/a/46467737/4866544)

Comment: @MatPag man it doesn't work inside buildscript brackets. It has to be   inside        allprojects {
    repositories {        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        } } }  . Tested by me. I'm using Android Studio 2.3.3

Comment: @GianGomen Usually it should be in both places. By default when you create a new project the `url "maven.google.com";` (now `google()`) is added in buildscript and allprojects

Answer (score 219, accepted):

Starting from version 26 of support libraries make sure that the `repositories` section includes a maven section with the "https://maven.google.com" endpoint.

Something like;

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why this is not included in the default templates? It's my first time into android studio how am I supposed to know this? I guess now i know how, but it tooked me a lot of time

Comment: Also, it doesn't work. I add this to my `repositories`, and I still get "Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0". Have I mentioned lately that I despise gradle?

Comment: @String and is it a good reason to downvote the answer? Check if you are adding in the buildscript block or the repository outside.

Comment: My apologies, and _mea culpa_ - I did have it in the `buildscript` block. Many thanks for pointing me in the direction of what I couldn't see. And I apologize for the downvote; my frustration was peaking after hours of fighting with this (and other things gradle), but that's not your fault.

Comment: this bug still exist although I added google() in android studio 3.0

Comment: You should have mentioned Project level gradle file.

Answer (score 26):

This is how I have it working.

1. Add `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }` as @Gabriele_Mariotti suggests above.

   ```
   allprojects {
       repositories {
           jcenter()
           maven {
               url "https://maven.google.com"
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Then on the build.gradle file inside the App folder add

   ```
   compileSdkVersion 26
   buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.xxx.yyy"
       minSdkVersion 16
       targetSdkVersion 26
   }
   ```
3. Then on the dependencies use

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
       compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
       compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
       compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1'
   }
   ```

Answer (score 17):

If you are using **Android Studio 3.0 or above** make sure your project **build.gradle** should have content similar to-

```
buildscript {                 
    repositories {
        google()  // add google() before jcenter()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {            
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()  // add google() before jcenter()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

And for **below Android Studio 3.0** and starting from **support libraries 26.+** your project **build.gradle** must look like this-

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

**Note-** position really matters add **google()** before **jcenter()**

check these links below for more details-

**1-** [Building Android Apps](https://guides.gradle.org/building-android-apps/)

**2-** [Add Build Dependencies](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html)

**3-** [Configure Your Build](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html)

Comment: this was life saver, Thank you

Answer (score 12):

Just add this to your main all project level build.gradle file under allprojects()

```
 maven {
    url "https://maven.google.com"
 }
```

Answer (score 10):

I face the same problem while I have updated my SDK and Android studio version(3.0 beta). I have solved this problem going through [this tutorial.](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-migration.html#ptb) In this they told us to update are build configuration file like

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 26
   buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
   defaultConfig {
   targetSdkVersion 26
  }
  ...
}

dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
}

// REQUIRED: Google's new Maven repo is required for the latest
// support library that is compatible with Android 8.0
repositories {
   maven {
       url 'https://maven.google.com'
       // Alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
   }
}
```

Hope it will help you out.

Answer (score 6):

in may case I found OneSignal changed their dependencies

so I changed it from

`compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.5.8, 3.99.99]'`

to

`compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.5.8, 3.5.8]'`

then it works, please check any unspecific dependency.

Answer (score 4):

Add this to the project level build.gradle file and it should work fine.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google() // this is to be added if there's something already.
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Google's new Maven repo is required for the latest support library that is compatible with Android 8.0.
Just update your Google's Maven repository like below:

To add them to your build, add `maven.google.com` to the Maven repositories in your module-level `build.gradle` file:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
        // Alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
    }
}
```

Alternative you can update `build.gradle` file like this:

```
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
```

Then add the desired library to your dependencies block. For example, the cardview library looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

in sdk 28
u can use

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

and remove cardView library

Answer (score 2):

Update your Android Support Repository from sdk manager.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to add google repository

1. Add `gradle-4.1-rc-1-all` in gradle-wrapper.properties.

   ```
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-rc-1-all.zip
   ```
2. Then add `google()` in the top-level build.gradle

   ```
   allprojects {
     repositories {
       google()
       jcenter()
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Simply change the build-version from
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'

to

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

If the other solutions here do not work, make sure you are **not in 'offline' mode**.  If enabled, android will not download the required files and you will get this error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try to compile

```
 compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Clean your gradle from terminal

```
./gradlew clean
```

then use this code in your build.gradle section

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure, your included library version is available. For your checking, you can use this [link](http://gradleplease.appspot.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when creating a new project in Android Studio using Kotlin. The way that finally helped me:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ionic 4, opened `/platforms/android/platform.properties`, changed the version of the listed library throwing the error (in my case, `com.android.support:support-v4:27.+`) to:

```
com.android.support:support-v4:28.+
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0'`
If you want version 26 you should use `compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-beta2'`, because it is beta for now

Answer (score 0):

```
android {
     compileSdkVersion 26
     buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
     useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

this is working for me

Answer (score 0):

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
```

This should pull the most recent version, and allow it to compile.

Comment: you shouldn't use plus signs in android gradle files because it makes the build non-deterministic.

Comment: Good to know! I appreciate your feedback and correction.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

goto **Android->sdk** make sure you have all depenencies required . if not , download them . then goto **File-->Settigs-->Build,Execution,Depoyment-->Gradle**

choose **use default gradle wapper (recommended)**

and untick **Offline work**

gradle build finishes successfully for once you can change the settings

Answer (score 0):

May be this problem is due to facebook library. 
Replace

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
```

by

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

@Aryan is correct [Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+ (Dependency Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164768/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v727-dependency-error)

A picture worth thousand words

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me I just had to clean my project.

Build -> Clean Project

Another time I had to:

File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files.

Answer (score 0):

2 Steps to fix this..
1, connect to internet.
2, Click on clean project. this will fix it 
:)

Answer (score 0):

When you sync this dependency to the android studio:

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1-alpha1'
```

Then, **Sync the Gradle with Project Files**.
It will say, (Suppose if you are working on new ones like androidx) obviously, it will show error on the dependency.

For that you can go to the **File menu** and click on the **invalidate/restart  the code**. It will resolve itself and the application will restart without any error.