# Error:(39, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0

Tags: android

I am using Android studio 2.3 and Thought for support new android 26 in my app.But I am stuck on error with title message. My gradle file is like below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"



    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.shayari"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "",
                                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }



    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta3'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.5.3,4.0.0)'
    compile 'com.codemybrainsout.rating:ratingdialog:1.0.7'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.6'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

But I am not able to install support repository with below error..

```
Error:(39, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0
<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:C:/Users/MAITRII/Desktop/newhindi/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45342389/6021469

Comment: Are you not clicking `<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a>`?

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46387821/3806413

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Add this to your project level `build.gradle` file:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple and efficient. Thanks!

Comment: what does it do

Answer (score 22):

**UPDATE:**
In Android studio 3.0 the error is solved.
Or you can add `google()` to solve it since you will use new the gradle plugin as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html?utm_campaign=android_update_gradle3.0.0_101217&utm_source=anddev&utm_medium=yt-desc).

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
        // You need to add the following repository to download the
        // new plugin.
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

---

**Before Android studio 3.0**:
Check if the support library is installed in your system (check the SDK directory in your system) or check if Android O is installed in the SDK Manager.

**Or as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103230/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportcardview-v726-0-0-android/45342389#45342389) answer stated**

> Starting from version 26 of support libraries make sure that the repositories section includes a maven section with the "https://maven.google.com" endpoint.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi ! Android O is installed in SDK manager. Thanks

Comment: The SDK is different from the support libraries

Comment: The support library is what is needed for the question

Comment: @cricket_007 thank you

Comment: Really save my day! Thank you!