# Error:(23, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.0 "Install Repository and sync project" dose not work

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I am trying to get location and update to server in my Android app. 
This is my Gradle code, here I included `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.0'`. This line is [from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'       
}
```

But this is the error I get:

```
Error:(23, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.0
Install Repository and sync project
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog
```

Clicking in "Install Repository and sync project" doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45696551/failed-to-resolve-com-google-firebasefirebase-core11-2-0)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Add this to your project-level `build.gradle` file:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
```

Comment: As per [Google Play services release notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases), dependencies are now available from `maven.google.com`

Answer (score 0):

Try update version new of google play service

1. Start Android Studio.
2. On the Tools menu, click Android > SDK Manager.
3. Update the Android Studio SDK Manager: click SDK Tools, expand Support
4. Repository, select Google Repository, and then click OK.

Answer (score 0):

In `build.gradle` file:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
```

Same problem and more solution here

[Error:(39, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45397066/error39-13-failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v726-0-0/45397095)