# Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0

Tags: android, firebase

I have a strange issue when integrate `firebase`:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please include the content of your gradle files.
Most likely you didn't include the google repository as stated here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45692460/failed-to-resolve-com-google-android-gmsplay-services-in-intellij-idea-with-gr

Answer (score 61):

if you integrate firebase automatically from tools, 
The new version of android studio have strange bug, the software inserts

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

instead of

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
```

fix this line (remove numbers after last ':')

[image]

Comment: I followed this step but it doesn't confirm that cloud storage is added to the app?

Comment: Very much thanks, I wasted a day for this...
I don't understand why google is doing such junk buggy releases...

Answer (score 12):

Remove the

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

and add only

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
```

> Because `16.0.1` is added by our self and while after that we connect firebase using the plugin in the studio, it adds a new lib file with `15.0.0`. 
>   So that's not required.

Comment: But why to remove 15.0.0?

Comment: because 16.0.15 is added by our self and while after that we connect firebase using the plugin in the studio, it adds new lib file with 15.0.0. so it not required

Answer (score 4):

### Step 1 :

In your root `build.gradle` file add the repo:

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
   google()
   maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
 }
}
```

Now Sync Gradle. This is the directory that contains the repos of Firebase.

### Step 2 :(if step 1 doesn't works)

If the Step 1 doesn't works, then it should be because you are using the Gradle in offline mode. If your gradle is set to offline, android studio searches for the cached copies of the dependencies that you want to update and throws an error since it hasn't downloaded the file before.
Go to `Settings` **>>** `Build, Execution, Deployment` **>>** `Gradle`.
In the `Global Gradle Settings` section, disable `Offline` mode.

Now Sync Gradle again.

Answer (score 1):

Use `implementation com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1` as many wrote before. But also add the line:  `kapt com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0`
this way firebase keep "Dependencies set up correctly".

Answer (score 0):

after

```css
implementation com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1
kapt 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

add the kapt, it fixed for me

Comment: CONFIGURE FAILED in 0s
Could not find method kept() for arguments [com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Answer (score 0):

Updated all the dependencies to

```
dependencies {
  implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1"
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
}
```

then build -> clean project, build -> rebuild project and is working