# Failed to resolve implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I am integrating Firebase messaging for a version. It is:

```
'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
```

My classpath is:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
```

I had faced the following error:

> Failed to resolve: firebase-messaging Open File

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change this:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
```

into this:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
```

**Explanation:**

Here in this case using `firebase-messaging:15.0.2` with `google-services:4.0.1` would work, since the most important thing was updating `google-services` above `3.2.0`, and that's because `google-services:3.3.0` is needed to be able to use the firebase library from version 15.0 and above. You can check this [blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html). that explains the changes in versioning of firebase libraries.

But it is still better to update the `google-services` plugin to prevent any other errors with other dependencies.

**Note:**

The versions less than `15.0.0` are in google maven repository, so you can use them in gradle. But, you cannot mix version `15.0.0` with a version less than `15.0.0` and use google play services `4.0.1`, as said in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51381727/android-cannot-add-all-google-libraries-for-version-15-0-1/51381916#51381916). That's why it is better to update firebase libraries to the latest versions.

Comment: Just curious, would it have also worked just updating to
`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'`

There should be a 15.0.2 version of firebase-messaging, as per maven.google.com

Comment: yes I think `15.0.2` would work with `4.0.1`, but the most important thing was updating google-services above `3.2.0`, since `google-services 3.3.0` is needed to be able to use the firebase library from version 15.0 and above. But anyway when I answered this I used the latest version of both `google-services` and firebase libraries to prevent any other issues if he is using other firebase libraries. @ZhiQiao

Comment: Also the maven.google.com just lists all the libraries inside the google() repo, there is also version 9.0 for some firebase libraries like `firebase-auth`, but it wont work if you use it with `google-services:4.0.1` (don't use it anyway since it is very old). @ZhiQiao

Comment: Cool. Thanks for following up. Glad this worked out. Just a minor caveat that since this was an update across major version (i.e. 15.0.2 => 17.0.0) it could potentially introduce API-breaking changes.

Comment: @ZhiQiao yes just to add The versions less than `15.0.0` are in google maven repo, so he can use them. But, he cannot mix version 15.0.0 with a version less than 15.0.0 and use google play services 4.0.1 (as said in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50732704/cannot-access-zzbfm-class-file-zzbfm-not-found-firebase-android/50732851#50732851). That is why it is better just to update the firebase libraries to the latest version after they release them. Also yes ofcourse he needs to check the release notes after he updates.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Guy4444 [1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7147289/guy4444) on the post [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52612817/4359933)  I have changed

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0:15.0.0'`

to

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'`

and it solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved by changing

this

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0:15.0.0'
```

to this

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
```