# Error: 'Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version....'

Tags: java, android, firebase, gradle, analytics

<s>**Full Error:** *'Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.8.0.'*</s>

**New Error**:
*'com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.'*

I've been getting this same error for a while, and I've tried changing around the versions to the 'com.google.android.gms' implementation, but nothing has worked. This only started happening when I tried adding Firebase Analytics to my app, but the Firebase integration itself went smoothly. Here are my app-level and project-level gradle files, as well as my google-services.json file:

**UPDATE:** This new main dex list error comes up whenever the compiler begins parsing my google-services.json file.

**App Level:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

repositories {
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/dasar/maven" }
    maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com" }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    jcenter()
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion project.sdkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.digitalnode.quickpick"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion project.sdkVersion
        versionName "v1.1"
        versionCode 17
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
        disable 'ExtraTranslation'
        abortOnError false
    }

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
    }

    // This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            resValue "string", "app_name", "LeafPic"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "QuickPic"
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "default"

    productFlavors {
        noGPlay {
            dimension "default"
        }

        withGPlay {
            dimension "default"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    //exifInterface
    implementation "com.android.support:exifinterface:$supportVersion"

    // google & support
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:palette-v7:$supportVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:$supportVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportVersion"

    //exo-player
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-smoothstreaming:2.6.0'

    // utils
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.12'
    implementation 'com.github.Commit451:bypasses:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.drewnoakes:metadata-extractor:2.11.0'
    implementation "com.orhanobut:hawk:2.0.1"
    implementation 'com.commonsware.cwac:provider:0.4.3'

    // rxJava
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
    //it is recommended to keep the same version of rxAndroid
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.13'
//    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxrelay2:rxrelay:2.0.0'

    // icons
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:3.0.3@aar'
    implementation "com.mikepenz:iconics-views:3.0.3@aar"
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:3.0.1.2.original@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:community-material-typeface:2.0.46.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.7.0.2@aar'

    // ui
    implementation 'uz.shift:colorpicker:0.5@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.jetradarmobile:desertplaceholder:1.1.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.2'
    implementation 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.10.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.7'
    implementation 'com.github.HoraApps:Liz:-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.2.1'

    // debug Only
    //debugCompile project(':inappstoragereader')
    implementation 'cat.ereza:customactivityoncrash:2.2.0'
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.4'
    releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.4'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    // TODO check them out
    implementation 'com.turingtechnologies.materialscrollbar:lib:10.0.3'
    implementation 'de.psdev.licensesdialog:licensesdialog:1.8.3'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.8.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
}

Properties props = new Properties()
def propFile = new File('signing.properties')
if (propFile.canRead()) {
    props.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))

    if (props != null && props.containsKey('STORE_FILE') && props.containsKey('KEY_ALIAS') && props.containsKey('PASSWORD')) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile = file(props['STORE_FILE'])
        android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = props['PASSWORD']
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias = props['KEY_ALIAS']
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = props['PASSWORD']
    } else {
        println 'signing.properties found but some entries are missing'
        android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
    }
} else {
    println 'signing.properties not found'
    android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Project Level:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

project.ext {
    supportVersion = "27.1.1"
    sdkVersion = 27
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Your `google-services` classpath, Kotlin version, gradle classpath, `firebase-core`, and probably others, are all pretty outdated. Update them first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have `firebase-core` added twice in your build.gradle file, so you need to remove the old one which is this:

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
```

Second change this:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.8.0'
```

into this:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.4'
```

To be able to use firebase dependencies with version 15.0.0+ you need to update the google-service plugin. The first version of this plugin that works with the new versioning system is `3.3.0`. The latest version is `4.2.0`, therefore update the `google-service` plugin to the following:

```
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Check the following for more information:

https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/4.2.0

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html

[Android | Cannot add all Google libraries for version 15.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51381727/android-cannot-add-all-google-libraries-for-version-15-0-1/51381916#51381916)

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem I was having, but it made way for yet another error: 'com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.' - This error comes up while it is parsing my google-services.json file. Do you suggest I make another post, or are these problems related?