# Failed to resolve: firebase-auth-15.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-authentication

Hello fellow developer i'm new to Android Development I just want to know how to resolve this kind of problem because i need to connect my app to firebase.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

    android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.acemergencyapp.user.aceapp"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
    }

    dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'
  }
```

I have a red line in `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`

Comment: Show the associated build or sync error as text in the question via an [edit]. A red underline in your IDE could be any number of things. Probably need to provide the top-level build.gradle, too, so we can see where you specify where to find dependencies.

Comment: The `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'` line is added by the Firebase assistant, for those wondering what they did wrong. As the answers say, delete the `:16.0.0` at the end of the line.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52612817/7147289

Answer (score 2):

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

Remove this dependency (last line)

You have already included version 16.0.3 above

Comment: thank you so much the problem fix but i have problem my `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` have red line

Comment: That is not an error, its a warning telling you that multiple versions of appcompat libraries are being used. Don't worry about it (for now, since you are new to android)

Comment: Ok sir copy that! You're a life savior thank you so much for your help . Sorry about the typo error im just newbie. i need to improve my skills! Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

you have two version numbers there... obviously a copy & paste fail.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

probably should rather be (which is already contained a few lines above):

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
```

... maybe read your `build.gradle`, before posting your typos here.

Comment: I remove it but  `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` have red line what should i do?

Comment: sorry about that sir im new to this i need more practice to see my errors

Comment: @Kenji if you would add the error message to the question, I possibly could tell how to fix that... but I need the concrete error message for that.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Navigate to `SDK Manager` -> `SDK Tools`.

First, click the `Android SDK Build-Tools` and install the latest update.

Second, click the `Android SDK Platform-Tools` and install the latest update.

This should fix the red line.

(Alternatively suppose if it does not go try the below code)

Write this:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

or this:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you sir i will try this! Thank you for the help