# How do i fix Authentication error android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYZFn.png)

> Hi, how do i fix Firebase authentication error - "failed to resolve: firebase-auth-15.0.0"

`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
            apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

```
        android {
            compileSdkVersion 28
            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "com.anton1111.azot2.antonio_chat"
                minSdkVersion 17
                targetSdkVersion 28
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0"
                testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            }
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
            }
        }

        dependencies {
            implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
            implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

            implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
            implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
            implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
            implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'


            testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
            androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
            androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'

        }`
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52504927/1531971

Answer (score 1):

you have the same implementation twice at your dependencies

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
```

and

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
```

remove the last one and just let `firebase-auth:16.1.0`

The one you posted in your photo has two versions, and that is causing the error

```
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0' <--- 16.0.1 and 15.0.0
```

delete one version and just use the latest one

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
```

Comment: it still doesn't work i can't make Authentication to app

Answer (score 0):

The stable version for gradle on **Firebase** website is:

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'`

You should give it a try to see if this works.

Answer (score 0):

Latest stable version for gradle on **FireBAse** is:

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'

You should give it and for more details please see [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start?gclid=CjwKCAiAo8jgBRAVEiwAJUXKqMJR0Jirth19oqF8yaRM8BdVTe7DCC0GG6nBM398a9cNUYtA01kOZRoC03oQAvD_BwE)