# Integrating google sign-in

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin

I'm trying to integrate google sign-in in my application, I've followed all the steps in the documentation but as I'm trying to run the app on my device now it says "Failed to resolve: play-services-basement"

Here is my app level gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.user.uberclone"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And here is my top level gradle:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {url "https://maven.google.com"}
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51139617/1008011), it explains the reason why you're seeing the `could not find play-services-basement.aar` error and also provides a solution: `jcenter()` should come after `google()` and `maven { url...}` in your dependencies.