# Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I'm getting multiple "Failed to Resolve" issues when syncing my project. They are all firebase and play-services related. I made sure they are all the same (11.2.0). I've also checked and the latest version for both is 11.2.0. Also, all the other answers to similar questions involve updating Google play services and repository in the SDK Manager but mine is already up to date.

[image]

[image]

Any idea why I can't sync my project?

**EDIT - Current working solution**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.0.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } 
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Post your project-level build.gradle file.

Comment: @BobSnyder Check my edit.

Comment: Move `google()` to `allprojects/repositories`

Comment: @BobSnyder Just made the change and I'm still getting 'Gradle DSL Method not found: 'google()' but I'm using Gradle version 2.3.3

Comment: Use `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }` instead of `google()`.

Comment: @BobSnyder That did the trick! I'm wondering why `google()` didn't work though...

Comment: Doesn't work for me either.  I'm going to ask @Gabriele (his answer below).

Comment: I tried with your solution, but it still throw same error.
Is there any other solution ?

Comment: @JayVyas did you make sure it's in the `allprojects/repositories` section instead of just `repositories`?

Comment: yes,
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

Comment: None of the answers here really worked for me. But I was able to debug all of my dependency issues via the `./gradlew :app:dependencies` command.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Add `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }` to your root level `build.gradle` file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Details in the [AS documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven)

Comment: @BobSnyder Just tried this. Added the maven repo and then changed my dependencies back to 11.2.0 and I got the same issues.

Comment: It worked but you need to apply in project level build gradle file

Comment: Make sure `maven {...}` is added under `allprojects/repositories`, that got me

Comment: While this solves to the problem I was having, I'm curious as to why it just came out of know where. I was using firebase fine in my project. Then I think the only thing I did was deleted a 3rd party library then syncing failed with this error

Answer (score 34):

**Play services** and **Firebase** dependencies are now available via `maven.google.com` with the release of version **11.2.0** of Google Play services and Firebase.

You can find the Google Play Services [official doc here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#august_2017_-_version_1120) and the [firebase doc here.](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/08/some-updates-to-apps-using-google-play.html).

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

If you are using the android gradle plugin 3.x you can also use:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried this with no luck. I checked my gradle version and it is 2.3.3. I also attempted simply adding `{url 'maven.google.com' }` which didn't work either.

Comment: `google()` doesn't work for me or the OP--see comments on question.  We are both using `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3`.  Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Update - turns out I was putting the `google()` repository in the wrong section. However, I had to use `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }` because `google()` isn't working for me or Bob.

Comment: @BobSnyder I've just updated the answer. google() repo seems work only with android gradle plugin 3.x

Comment: For anyone interesting in using version 3.0.0 of the Android Plugin for Gradle, [here are the migration instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html).

Comment: Thanks, you saved my days. For Quickblox user while running their sample project from git , We need to add google() in project level graddle as it`s version is 3.x .

Answer (score 12):

I just fixed same error by adding **firebase-core** dependency.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

Comment: I had not put in the `:16.0.1`

Comment: you know what is the issue with : 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0' it's not working when i'm using with my flutter app.

Answer (score 2):

With the `16.0.0` release of firebase I had to

- set **most** my google play services libraries to `15.0.0`  analytics and tagmanager needed to be `16.0.0`
- set my support library versions to `27.1.1`
- firebase-core to `16.0.0`

Built against sdk 27

Extra Changes:

I also had to  update my analytics to 16.0.0

- implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.0"

Part of the independent versions thing Android did recently I am guessing. May need to try going up or down a version on the google play services and firebase libraries

Answer (score 1):

The best Method to fix this problem is not using the manual method of linking firebase to your app.

I have tried adding latest firebase repo by referring to this 
    [Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) .

It showed error " failed to resolve the dependencies firebase 11.2.0"

FireBase recommends adding firebase to your app with the help of FireBase Assistant for Android Studio Version 2.2 and Higher. Manually adding the latest library to build-gradle(module) result in an error as above.

Firebase assistant added lower versions 10.0.1 automatically to dependencies on the module gradle-build which is compatible and could be resolved.

Using Firebase assistant is so easy and 2 step process. For reference, You can use the "Use the Firebase Assistant" section on the same link mentioned above.

It Really worked Out with my Android Studio 2.3.3. And also make sure Your Google Repository is up to date

Answer (score 0):

From tools-> sdk manager-> sdk tools  install google play service and google repository and sync your project will work fine