# NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzEq()Z in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp;

Tags: java, android, maven, firebase, nosuchmethoderror

Below is the fatal error that I keep getting on my App. I am trying to run a chat messenger feature on my application using Firebase. It was running however it has since kept crashing the app entirely. I've made a few edits to the code in the hope of resolving the issues, but to no avail.

I've been following this tutorial on youtbe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xn0tQHpMDnM and it appears by reading the comments that no one else has a similiar error to me.

According to the log, the errors are found on line 99 -  `displayChatMessage();` as well as on Line 109 - `adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(this,ChatMessage.class,R.layout.chat_list_item,FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()) {`

I'm hoping this maybe just a simple code error which I have created, or is it possible it could be to do with my gradle build. Below is the error log I am getting.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                     Process: com.example.aids.a09application, PID: 30713
                                                                                     java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzEq()Z in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.example.aids.a09application-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes33.dex)
                                                                                         at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                                         at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                                         at com.example.aids.a09application.MainChatActivity.displayChatMessage(MainChatActivity.java:109)
                                                                                         at com.example.aids.a09application.MainChatActivity.onCreate(MainChatActivity.java:99)
                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6912)
                                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2877)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Below is the MainActivity Class for the chat messenger in my application:

```
package com.example.aids.a09application;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;

import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

/**
 * Created by Aids on 29/08/2017.
 */

public class MainChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static int SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage> adapter;
    RelativeLayout chat_activity_main;
    FloatingActionButton fab;

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == (R.id.menu_signout))
        {
            AuthUI.getInstance().signOut( this ).addOnCompleteListener( new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    Snackbar.make( chat_activity_main, "You have been signed out.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();

                }
            } );
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.chat_main_menu, menu );
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult( requestCode, resultCode, data );
        if (requestCode == SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                Snackbar.make( chat_activity_main, "Succesfully signed in. Welcome!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                displayChatMessage();
            }
            else {
                Snackbar.make( chat_activity_main, "We couldn't sign you in. Please try again!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.chat_activity_main );

        chat_activity_main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById( R.id.chat_activity_main );
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById( R.id.fab );
        fab.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EditText input = (EditText)findViewById( R.id.input );
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().setValue( new ChatMessage(input.getText().toString(),
                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail()));
                input.setText( "" );

            }
        } );

        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
            startActivityForResult( AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().build(), SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE );
        } else {
            Snackbar.make( chat_activity_main, "Welcome" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            //Load Content
            displayChatMessage();
        }



    }

    private void displayChatMessage() {

        ListView listofMessage = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.list_of_messages );
        adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(this,ChatMessage.class,R.layout.chat_list_item,FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
                //Get references to the views of chat_list_item.xml

                TextView messageText, messageUser, messageTime;
                messageText = (TextView) v.findViewById( R.id.message_text );
                messageUser = (TextView) v.findViewById( R.id.message_user );
                messageTime = (TextView) v.findViewById( R.id.message_time );

                messageText.setText( model.getMessageText() );
                messageUser.setText( model.getMessageUser() );
                messageTime.setText( DateFormat.format( "dd-mm-yyyy (HH:MM:SS)",model.getMessageTime() ) );
            }
        };

        listofMessage.setAdapter( adapter );

    }

}
```

Gradle Build Module:App

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.aids.a09application"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
        aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })


    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0' // ADDED
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.2.0' // ADDED
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.3.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: `or is it possible it could be to do with my gradle build` - well we'd need to see that as well? Also this is a direct pull from this repo - https://github.com/eddydn/ChatApp ?

Comment: no not a direct Pull, similiar but not the same.

Comment: I see, does a direct clone build?

Comment: no, the direct clone doesn't build as that ChatApp on GitHub had custom imports, that kept throwing compile errors.

Comment: .. strange just cloned and built fine .. I think `compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.3.0'` contains `core` and a load of other firebase dependencies, so you probably have a transitive problem - try removing everything other than `compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.3.0'` for firebase - I'd suggest looking at your external libraries when you do a gradle sync, it will show all the dependencies you have.

Comment: Does this new question mean the sync error reported in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45946241/4815718) were resolved?

Comment: In your previous question, you were only depending on `firebase-ui-auth`, now you also have `firebase-ui`.  Do you need it?  If so, additional changes are needed to your dependencies.

Comment: I'll try remove the firebase-ui-auth and keep the firebase-ui. I need the core, messaging aspects of Firebase for push notificications.

Comment: /data/app/com.example.aids.a09application-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes32.dex) - I have this in my Logcat. any ideas?

Comment: Anyone able to help - Still not working. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem while reading/writing to firebase database this small change worked for me. Try removing unnecessary firebase dependencies and make sure you **use the same version for all the firebase dependencies** for those that you use. In my case I changed my firebase dependencies from:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
```

to these:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
```

I'm sure you might have spent a lot of time trying to fix this. Might as well turn out worth a shot :)