# can't compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.1.1'

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebaseui

> I dont know why my gradle can't import firebase ui
>   [Error when I'm import Firebase UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fx9KQ.png)

compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.1.1'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45696551/failed-to-resolve-com-google-firebasefirebase-core11-2-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put your firebase ui dependency according to your normal firebase dependency, take a look at this.

[image]

In your case you would have to use the firebase normal dependencies version 11.0.2, or change your firebase ui version.