# Firebase duplicate files build error

Tags: android, firebase, duplicates, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

I have been developing and working on my App, I then decided to build the APK I then got duplicate file error specifically talking about firebase zzc.class? which I could not find. I have seen duplicate file error before and sorted it out but this Firebase error has really slowed down my work because I have seen no specific answer to my issue.

Below are my dependencies

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.+'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.0.1'
compile 'org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:2.0.0'
compile 'net.igenius:customcheckbox:1.3'
compile 'com.roger.catloadinglibrary:catloadinglibrary:1.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Then the error:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using different versions of the same libraries:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.0.1'
```

As you can [read here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries) there is a dependency between firebaseui and firebase libraries:

```
FirebaseUI Version  Firebase/Play Services Version
2.3.0               11.0.4
2.2.0               11.0.4
2.1.1               11.0.2
2.0.1               11.0.1
```

**Use the same version to avoid these issue.**

Also there is no reason to use the old:

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:x.x.x'
```

Check the [migration guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android) and use:

```
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:X.X.X"
```

Keep in mind that the latest version requires the [google maven repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45696551/failed-to-resolve-com-google-firebasefirebase-core11-2-0/45698056#45698056):

```
allprojects {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have a duplicate in your build.gradle file. To solve this, you need to remove the following line of code:

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
```

You cannot mix the old version of dependency with the new one.

Comment: No it does not it still gives the same error, I was trying to play with the dependencies a little to see if it will go but the error just kept on changing to worse ones. So for now the error is the same after removing firebase-client :(

Comment: Update all your dependencies to `11.0.4` version kepping that line commented. Any changes?

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure to update firebase version to latest available version in your build(app) configuration exactly mentioned in the firebase documentation.**

[[https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup/]](http://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup/)

**If you are using play services make sure that the version of firebase library should be exactly same as of play services version.**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.2.0'
```

**If there is a library conflict then add gradle as:**

```
 defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

**and in your baseapplication**

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Comment: Just follow the documentation add build dependencies as mentioned at the web link