# Google play services in Android Studio don't work

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api, google-play-services

I'm having some problems using google play services in Android Studio. I'm try using 11.2.2 version but it seems I don't have installed it. I can't update my current version which is 11.0.4

Here are my google play services dependence in my build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.2.2'
```

And here my errors:

```
Error:(30, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.2
Error:(31, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.2.2
```

If I use version 11.0.4 instead of 11.2.2 the code seems to work.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45696551/failed-to-resolve-com-google-firebasefirebase-core11-2-0

Comment: Also have a look at this: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven

Comment: Thanks! I've added Maven repositories and it work. But how can I add play services dependencies without add repositories code in build.gradle file? Is it possible?

Comment: @Marco It is not possible to add dependencies without to add the repository (where they are).