# Android : gradlew lint error "Incompatible Gradle Versions"

Tags: android, gradle, lint, gradlew

I am having issues while running '**gradlew lint**' on my Android Library Project since I upgraded my gradle wrapper version and build tools version.

I was previously using gradlew version 1.3.0 and buildToolsVersion of 23.0.0 I had no issues while running **lint**.

After upgrading my gradlew version and buildTools versions, I started having this error while running '**gradlew lint**'

I am using gradlew version

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```

Then on my build.gradle (app) I am using

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
```

My play-services version is

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
```

From the lint results this is the error ouput

```
Incompatible Gradle Versions
../../build.gradle: All com.android.support libraries must use 
 the exact same version specification 
(mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). 
Found versions 26.0.0-alpha1, 22.2.0. 
Examples include com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0-alpha1 
and com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0
```

I have a gut feeling that this is issue is caused by play-services and android buildTools version however I don't have an idea on how to fix it.

Now when I run '**./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration compile**'

I get this from the play-services section

```
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.1.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0 -> 26.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0-alpha1 -> 23.0.1
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0-alpha1 -> 23.0.1
|    |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0-alpha1 -> 23.0.1
|    |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0-alpha1 -> 23.0.1
|    |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:26.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |              +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |              +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |              \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0-alpha1 (*)
```

Note : I only displayed the play-services part as this is what I saw from the Lint Results and I think this is the only part that would be useful.

can anyone tell me what play-services version should I be using with buildToolsVersion 25 and compiledSdkVersion 25?

Thanks!

app build.gradle

```
import com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin
import org.aspectj.bridge.IMessage
import org.aspectj.bridge.MessageHandler
import org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'


android {
  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
  }

  compileSdkVersion 25
  buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
  }
  buildTypes {
    debug {
      buildConfigField "String", "APP_VERSION", "\"1.0-SNAPSHOT\""
    }
    release {
      buildConfigField "String", "APP_VERSION", "\"1.0-SNAPSHOT\""

      minifyEnabled true
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro', 'proguard-rules-app.pro'
    }
  }

  configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
      force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
    }
  }

  sourceSets {
    defaultConfig {
      testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }
  }

}

buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
    classpath 'org.aspectj:aspectjtools:1.8.9'
  }
}

repositories {
  maven {
    url 'https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2'
  }
  maven {
    url "https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/"
  }
}


apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
def dbflow_version = "3.1.1"


dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'
  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.0.1'

  apt "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-processor:${dbflow_version}"
  compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-core:${dbflow_version}"
  compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow:${dbflow_version}"
  compile 'com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-sqlcipher:3.1.1@aar'
  compile 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.1'
  compile 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.7.2'

  compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
  compile 'commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1'

  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
  compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
  compile 'com.scottyab:aescrypt:0.0.1'

  compile([group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.3.2'],
          [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.3.2'],
          [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.3.2'])

  compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.9'
  compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'

  compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
  compile('com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-6') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android'
  }
  compile 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.5.5'
  compile 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.5.5'

  compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:20.50.533.12'


  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  testCompile group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'mockwebserver', version: '3.9.0'
  testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock:1.6.5'
  testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.5'

  testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.5'
  testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'



}
```

Comment: Please include your app `build.gradle` in your question.

Comment: please post your Build.gradle here

Comment: updated the question with app build.gradle

Comment: make your build tool version to 26 or make the gradle file extend 25.x.x instead of 26.x.x

Comment: @Pranav how do I do that "extend 25.x.x"? Can you give me an example.

Comment: have you tried making compileSdkVersion 25 to 26

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Found versions 26.0.0-alpha1, 22.2.0. 
>   Examples include com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0-alpha1 
>   and com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0

**You are using libraries with different version of support libraries**.
In particolar you are using `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0` and `com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0-alpha1`.

Update to latest version in particolar way use the support libraries v.26 and the google play services libraries v.11.2.0.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
```

Also keep in mind that the [**support libraries v26**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103230/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportcardview-v726-0-0-android/45342389#45342389) and [**google play services v.11.2.0**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45696551/failed-to-resolve-com-google-firebasefirebase-core11-2-0/45698056#45698056) require `compileSdkVersion 26` and **the google maven repo** `url "https://maven.google.com"`.

If you would like to exclude `com.android.support` library you can use:

```
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.2'){
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

Comment: If the OP claims to have the latest Gradle, then `google()` repository will work too

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes correct. You need gradle v.4  and the gradle plugin 3.x+.

Comment: I finally figured it out, this helped me, but I had to exclude group: 'com.android.support' in my play-services dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, Google Play Services is picking a version that's older than what you want for support-v4

```
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services- basement:8.1.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0
```

> what play-services version should I be using with buildToolsVersion 25 and compiledSdkVersion 25?

Those numbers don't really matter all that much. But you'll ideally always want to have the latest compile SDK (depending on resource or method deprecation and removals) and Build tools. At least, I've never had a problem with that approach.

As for Google Play, [go read the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split). Specifically the section on selectively compiling what you actually need