# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0

Tags: java, android, android-support-library

Mark my question by This [Question Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103230/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportcardview-v726-0-0-android) but the question is not similar to this question.The reason is - "com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0" dependency not added to my project. The question has different reason and different error. Also the answer of [Question Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103230/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportcardview-v726-0-0-android) is not work for this problem.

I am using **Android Studio 2.3.3** and **Android Studio 3.0 BETA 6** side by side in my pc. In my project I get the error as below image -

[image]

I am using dependencies-

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.karumi:dexter:4.1.1'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1.1@aar'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.7.0'
    compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.7.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and use -

`compileSdkVersion 26
 buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"`

in the gradle file I use this code -

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.0.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I am stuck to find this problem solution.

Comment: this is not **error** just download that repository than **clean-Revuild*run**

Comment: @NileshRathod I already try this. It is not work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103230/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportcardview-v726-0-0-android

Follow the above link, this might help you.

Comment: above link solution not work.

Comment: Pay attention that in the project's (not the module) build.gradle file there are 2 repositories blocks, you need to add the url https://maven.google.com to the second block nested in allprojects

Comment: Uncheck "Offline work" for Gradle (Menu: File -> Settings -> Gradle).

Answer (score 8):

You have to add `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` in `repositories` section.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
 }
}
```

Comment: not work. it give -  Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.0

Comment: @MahmudurRahman I think you dont need firebase plugin in classpath because you already have google services. check my edited answer.

Comment: Its still give same error.

Comment: Use **Install Repository and Sync Project**. if this option is available in error message.

Comment: I already do this, after sync the same error appears.

Comment: this "com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0" dependency is not available in your dependencies list. than how came up this error message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154748/discussion-between-akash-patel-and-mahmudur-rahman).

Comment: You need to add maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } to another section
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}