# Android P Error: Unable to resolve dependency issue

Tags: android, gradle, android-9.0-pie

After updating the Target version `P`  getting error

> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.8.0.
>   Open File
> Show Details

1.I added the  `google()`  in project gradle file

2.I have also checked by doing sync and clean project.

I checked below links

[Unable to resolve all dependencies in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47073333/unable-to-resolve-all-dependencies-in-android-studio)

[Unable to resolve dependency Android Studio 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47001656/unable-to-resolve-dependency-android-studio-3-0)

1.App/Gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    android {
compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId 'com.ctdiindia.b2b'
            minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 'P'
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            multiDexEnabled true

        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
            debug {
                debuggable true
            }
        }
        buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
        productFlavors {
        }
        compileOptions {
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }

    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        //Testing
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
        testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'
        // Firebase
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.8.0'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
        // Firebase UI
        compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'
        //Reycycler View
        implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
        //Networking
        implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
        compile 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.1'
        //Observabale librares
        compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
        compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.8'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

2.Project/Gradle

```
    buildscript {

        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'


            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }


        }
    }
```

Anyone had this similar issue?

Comment: share your **`build.gradle`** with quetsion

Comment: @NileshRathod  shared gradle image

Comment: not image whole gradle file

Comment: Do you need app/gradle or project/gradle

Comment: both if possible

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Actually this dependency issue not only for firebase

Comment: Could you share Both `build.gradle`

Comment: @NileshRathod updated question

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Updated question

Comment: use `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166654/discussion-between-r2r-and-intellij-amiya).

Comment: please ref.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48171692/unable-to-resolve-all-dependencies-in-android-studio-3-0-1/51359061#51359061
 my answer on same issue if it helps you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.8.0'
```

use:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.8.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0
```

Instead of this

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.8.0'
```

[**FROM DOCS**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) : `com.google.firebase:firebase-core` is a recommended alias for the `com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics` library.

> **The following libraries are available for the various Firebase features.**

```
Gradle Dependency Line  Service
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0            Analytics
com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0        Realtime Database
com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0       Cloud Firestore
com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0         Storage
com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0           Crash Reporting
com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0            Authentication
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0       Cloud Messaging
com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8.0          Remote Config
com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.8.0         Invites and Dynamic Links
com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0             AdMob
com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.8.0     App Indexing
com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.8.0            Performance Monitoring
```

Comment: I agree the recommendation but it doesnot solve my problem

Comment: did you update `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'` as per docs suggestion

Comment: @R2R you mention in question `Android P Error` but you ddin't  use android- p in gradle file about Android P

Comment: Updated question

Comment: @R2R https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#3-0-0