# Error: app is in background uid null

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I created a new Android project on IntelliJ CE 2017.2 and got [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103230/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportcardview-v726-0-0-android/45342389#45342389). I added the maven section as described in the answer.

When I run the default app that is created with the new project I get the error

> Error while executing: am startservice com.test.myapp/com.android.tools.fd.runtime.InstantRunService
>
> Starting service: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.test.myapp/com.android.tools.fd.runtime.InstantRunService }
>
> Error: app is in background uid null

I can still open the app manually on my phone and it works, but it doesn't start automatically and I get that error message.

Answer (score 28):

I've seen this error using android api 26/27 (Oreo).  In Oreo there are new [background execution limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html).  tl;dr you should run services in the foreground.

to start your service using adb, use `adb shell am start-foreground-service`

instead of `adb shell am startservice`.

Comment: How do you change that in IntelliJ? I can only set launch flags but not change the command!?

Comment: As a workaround, you can disable Instant Run. Go to Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run. Uncheck "Enable Instant Run to hot swap code/resource changes on deploy (default enabled)"

Comment: @shadanan This worked. I am not getting the error anymore and the app does start automatically. If you post this as answer I will mark it as the correct one.

Comment: Thanks, This is exactly what i need. AI could not give me this command SO.. rocks

Answer (score 7):

## Oreo (26+) requires services in the foreground

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    context.startForegroundService(intent);
}
else {
    context.startService(intent);
}
```

**IMPORTANT** After the service starts, `Service.startForeground()` must be called within 5 seconds. The obvious place is within `onCreate`