# How do I start the SpeakEasy service from androidx.test.services?

Tags: android

I have a package, `androidx.test.services` ([download link for APK](https://maven.google.com/androidx/test/services/test-services/1.4.2/test-services-1.4.2.apk)), and within the package, there is a service called the `androidx.test.services.speakeasy.server.SpeakEasyService` that is exported. I would like to start this service as a foreground service via `adb` such that when I run `adb shell pm dump androidx.test.services`, the `DUMP OF SERVICE usagestats` section contains the following lines under the `Last 24 hour events`.

```
    time="2023-07-10 14:26:11" type=STANDBY_BUCKET_CHANGED package=androidx.test.services standbyBucket=10 reason=u-si flags=0x0 
    time="2023-07-10 14:26:11" type=FOREGROUND_SERVICE_START package=androidx.test.services class=androidx.test.services.speakeasy.server.SpeakEasyService flags=0x0 
    time="2023-07-10 14:26:11" type=NOTIFICATION_INTERRUPTION package=androidx.test.services channelId=test_services_channel_id flags=0x0 
    time="2023-07-10 14:26:20" type=FOREGROUND_SERVICE_STOP package=androidx.test.services class=androidx.test.services.speakeasy.server.SpeakEasyService flags=0x0
```

Would anybody happen to know what actions to take to reproduce these log lines? Below is the procedure that I have done so far which has not successfuly started the a service.

1. Install the `androidx.test.services` APK with `$ adb install <apk path>`
2. Change the standby bucket of the app from 50 to 10 with `$ adb shell am set-standby-bucket androidx.test.services 10` (this makes it active and creates the first line in the log with the `STANDBY_BUCKET_CHANGED` event type).
3. Attempt to start the only service that is exported from the APK which is this `androidx.test.services.speakeasy.server.SpeakEasyService` service. I attempted to start this with `$ adb shell am startservice androidx.test.services/.speakeasy.server.SpeakEasyService`. However, I get an error stating that `app is in background uid null`. To fix that, I ran it as a [foreground service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47209662/error-app-is-in-background-uid-null) instead according to that SO post.
4. As a result, I ran `adb shell am start-foreground-service androidx.test.services/.speakeasy.server.SpeakEasyService`.  This command appears to work fine where it just outputs the following text

```
Starting service: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=androidx.test.services/.speakeasy.server.SpeakEasyService }
```

However, when I check the `DUMP OF SERVICE usagestats` section, I find that there is no line that states that the `FOREGROUND_SERVICE_START` event, despite the output saying that the intent was started. I was wondering if anybody would happen to know what might be causing this issue with the foreground service not starting or being recorded in the log.

I'm new to Android, so I might be missing a conceptual understanding of how this works. If there is any information that I can provide, please let me know. Thanks!