# Updating Gradle Dependencies in Android Projects

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-support-library

every now and then I experience the same problem with updating the support library dependencies in the gradle file.

At the moment I use the version 26.0.0-alpha1

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'
```

Furthermore my setup is like this

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 26
```

To update the repositories I use

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        }
    }
```

Today I updated all tools and now all of the support libraries are marked with the message

```
A newer version of com.android.support:recyclerview-v7 than 26.0.0-alpha1 is available: 26.1.0
```

So I change the version of the library to 26.1.0

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
```

But this leads to the error

```
Failed to resolve: com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0
```

So I change my setup to

```
buildToolsVersion '26.1.0'
```

But this leads to the error

```
Failed to find Build Tools revision 26.1.0
Install Build Tools 26.1.0 and sync project
```

So I click on "Install ..." and it leads to the error

```
All packages are not available for download!
The following packages are not available:
- Package id build-tools;26.1.0
```

It feels like Android Studio is goofing me. Can someone tell me a working way to update the libraries?

Comment: `maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }`

Comment: I already use this (added it to the post)

Comment: Marking it as duplicate is wrong. The other question is similar but has a different topic.

Comment: Reopen your question.

Answer (score 0):

Update your project level build.gradle file with this one

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And your buildToolVersion should be like this : `buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'` or update to latest `27.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

> Failed to resolve: com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0

You have to add the [google maven repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103230/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportcardview-v726-0-0-android/45342389#45342389) in your `repositories` block. You are adding it only in the block under the `buildscript` block and it is different.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}
```

> Failed to find Build Tools revision 26.1.0

**It doesn't exist**. Use an existing version.
You can [check here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link. It is helpful. You mentioned that 26.1.0 does not exist but why does Android Studio suggest to use version 26.1.0? That makes no sense to me / irritates me.