# Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle

I tried almost everything. Nothing helps. When I'm adding this lib `compile 'com.github.bassaer:chatmessageview:1.10.0'`, it gives error like this `Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0`.

Here my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.supportop"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile('io.github.sac:SocketclusterClientJava:1.7.4') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    compile 'com.github.bassaer:chatmessageview:1.10.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

As you see I'm using version 25.3.1 , so when I'm removing the lib `compile 'com.github.bassaer:chatmessageview:1.10.0'`, the problem disappears. What can I do here? Invalidate catches, rebuild project and clean project not helps.

[image: Here the image]

Comment: Click on Error link please. Install

Comment: What are your gradle and android plugin versions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to resolve: com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0 android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103230/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportcardview-v726-0-0-android)

Comment: Can you provide your app level *build.gradle* also ?

Answer (score 0):

As google suggest it is best to upgrade to the newer version of android using the latest version of `BuildTools`, `CompileSDK` and `supportLibraries`.

However if you really have to work with this particular version of support libraries you can remove the **transitive dependency** that **chatmessageview** have like this:

```
compile ('com.github.bassaer:chatmessageview:1.10.0'){
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module:'appcompat-v7'
}
```

But remember that this library may had a good reason to use a newer version of supportLibs. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you

Add this in project gradle file support library requires google() as a mevan

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Because the `com.github.bassaer:chatmessageview:1.10.0` library using the `buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"` and while you add it to your `dependencies` it will go to find the given `buildToolsVersion` synchronization and if it doesn't found it will throw you `Failed to resolve 26.1.0` because the library configured on this version.

So either you need to go to library `build.gradle` file and downgrade it's `buildToolsVersion` and `dependencies` same as yours. Or you need to upgrade your `SDK` if not for that just click on `Install repository and sync project`. It will download the required components and you may be able to sync your projects then after.

But i suggest to not downgrading the `buildToolsVersion` of library instead install require components. Because library may dependent new features on latest version.