# com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2

Tags: android, firebase

I'm having a lot of issues when I changed firebase version to 11.4.2, it was working well before. But when I changed it caused several issues such 
as:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2
       Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0
       Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0
         Error:Failed to resolve: android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0-beta1
```

Gradle

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 27
        buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.andisofttechnology.foodapp"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        //Add Library
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.1'
        compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
        compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

app

```
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'


            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
         /*   maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }*/
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

But when I changed it caused several issues such 
    as:But when I changed it caused several issues such 
    as:But when I changed it caused several issues such 
    as:But when I changed it caused several issues such 
    as:But when I changed it caused several issues such 
    as:
But when I changed it caused several issues such 
    as:
But when I changed it caused several issues such 
    as:

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45342389

Comment: put same version 28.0.2 for all supported library, and for Firebase 11.4.2

Comment: Thank you for your reply,even if I changed line,it still shows the same issue com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good thing to specify in our projects the last stable version of the libraries we use, specially when it comes with libraries such as Firebase, that could lead to a lot of dependency conflicts.

You can find the latest versions for each Firebase's library here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available_libraries

Refer to them in your build.gradle, and your issue should be solved.