# Android - Failed to resolve: cardview-v7

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest, android-support-library

My `gradle` is like bellow:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.11.2'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
//apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-crash'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "qq.qq.qq"
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "11-0a8b-1-1-11",
                                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "1111"]
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 13
        versionName "2.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
                checkReleaseBuilds false
                // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
                // but continue the build even when errors are found:
                abortOnError false
            }
            minifyEnabled false
            //shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    //implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.9'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-android:0.20.3'
    implementation 'com.joanzapata.iconify:android-iconify-fontawesome:2.2.2'
    implementation 'com.joanzapata.iconify:android-iconify-material:2.2.2'
    implementation 'com.joanzapata.iconify:android-iconify-material-community:2.2.2'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.10.1, 3.99.99]'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.1'
    //DNS
    implementation 'org.pcap4j:pcap4j-core:1.7.3'
    implementation 'org.pcap4j:pcap4j-packetfactory-static:1.7.3'
    implementation 'org.minidns:minidns-client:0.3.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
        classpath ('com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5') {
            exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5'
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven { url "https://storage.googleapis.com/snap-kit-build/maven" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

But get me bellow error:

```
Failed to resolve: cardview-v7
```

When I use from `./gradlew dependencies` get me bellow message:

```
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
```

And here is my `manifest`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ww.ww.ww">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <!--ByPass-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/logo_squre"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/logo_round"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="asset_statements"
            android:resource="@string/asset_statements" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT"
            android:value="DISABLE" />

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />

        </provider>

        <provider
            android:name="w.w.w.tools.GenericFileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.openpdf"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths_external" />

        </provider>

        <activity
            android:name=".start.StartActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".main.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|uiMode|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
                android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".listfieldsdegree.ListFieldsDegreeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".contentlistfieldsdegree.ContentListFieldDegreeWebViewActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <service android:name=".downloader.DownloadService" />

        <service android:name=".downloaderkayako.DownloadServiceKayako" />

        <activity
            android:name=".shorttermcourses.ShortTermCoursesActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".aboutus.AboutUsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ww.ShortTermCourseSelectedActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <service
            android:name=".fragments.ww.ww.GetContactListLocaleService"
            android:process=":GetContactListLocaleService" />

        <!--region ByPass-->
        <service
            android:name=".bypass.service.DaedalusVpnService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.VpnService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".ww.service.DaedalusTileService"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_security"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver android:name=".ww.receiver.BootBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".ww.receiver.StatusBarBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="ww.ww.ww.bypass.ww.StatusBarBroadcastReceiver.STATUS_BAR_BTN_DEACTIVATE_CLICK_ACTION" />
                <action android:name="ww.ww.ww.bypass.receiver.StatusBarBroadcastReceiver.STATUS_BAR_BTN_SETTINGS_CLICK_ACTION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".ww.ww.StartByPassActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <!--endregion-->
    </application>

</manifest>
```

What can I do?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103230/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportcardview-v726-0-0-android

Comment: @Hetvi Gandhi. We have just 27.0.3 or 28.0.0.  !!!!!!

Comment: try to delete `buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it to like bellow and good work:

```
compileSdkVersion 28
targetSdkVersion 28
```

And:

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha2'
implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```