# How to fix : ERROR: Failed to resolve: 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

Tags: android, gradle, androidx, cardview

I'm developing a new android application by using **androidx libraries**, and i need to use **cardview** in my layout.
so i try to add cardview library to my project but i get this error `ERROR: Failed to resolve: cardview`

i check answers of [Failed: com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0 android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103230/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportcardview-v726-0-0-android), but it doesn't help me
answers like

- add `google()` before `jcenter()`
- add `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }` to `repositories`

---

build.gradle(project)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.chavosh.porterageapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'
    testImplementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // recycler view
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha04'

    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

}
```

build.gradle(moudle)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.21"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

gradle.properties has this two line

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

[image: error pic]

Comment: can you please clean build project or invalidate restart android studio.

Comment: Try to add `android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true` in your `gradle.properties` file. Also please check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52181574/android-failed-to-resolve-cardview-v7 Also please check https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate It can help you more

Comment: @MehulKabaria thanks for your answer. i tried restarting android studio but nothing happens

Comment: @AjayMehta-Rlogical i just edit the question , thanks but my `gradle.properties` file had `android.useAndroidX=true android.enableJetifier=true`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just remove them!

With just those 3 you can use both `RecyclerView` and `CardView` and a plus as well: `ConstraintLayout`

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0-alpha05'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

Comment: No worries :) I also struggled a lot. Question @hassanmoradnezhad did you manually converted to androidX or used the AndroidStudio converter tools? If so, you might want to report a bug to Google stating that the converter hadn't remove those lines from the `build.gradle` file

Answer (score 0):

Add MaterialComponents:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06'
```

See this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57833454/11720798

Comment: yeah, material card view now is available in the material library with more options. but I was looking for `androidx.cardview:cardview`

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Tick download in CardView of Palette/layout to solve this problem