# Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/support-fragment/28.0.0/support-fragment-28.0.0.aar'

Tags: android, fragment, aar

I want to build a simple fragment based App, but I can't load the lib.

Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/support-fragment/28.0.0/support-fragment-28.0.0.aar'

What I tried:

1. update Proxy settings
2. delete Proxy
3. settings Check
4. check Connection
5. Add:

```
   // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
         maven {
             url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

## Gradle.Properties

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.fragmentmanagementmainactivity"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-beta1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0'
}
```

All started with implementation of 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
which wasn't working

Comment: You may want to include a little bit more of your gradle file than just this.

Comment: _the other_ one, where you declare your dependencies :) (if you add `google()` which you already have, then you shouldn't need the maven one for appcompat stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You're either importing a wrong dependency in your (app) build.gradle, or
2. You've got some DNS problems on your device/network.
3. You might be able to try this too; 
   Add this to the app build.gradle

```
repositories {
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
```

I hope it's either of these because they're easy to solve. Let me know if it got solved.

Edit: add 3

Comment: to 1. I added them via Project Strukture search so they are not wrong
to 2. I Checkt connection (See above) and I can Donwload the files Manually when chlick on the link
to 3. I already did

Comment: I've read several cases like this one, it mostly comes down to your native system blocking network requests. Does it work when you go on a different network / turn on firewall?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103230/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportcardview-v726-0-0-android/45342389

Comment: I tried an other Network. This is working for me. Pls +1 Question

Comment: You can set it as the accepted answer. @Alpha-Centauri