# Could not find swiperefreshlayout.jar (androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0)

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to react-native run-android there is this problem??

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-screens:debugCompileClasspath'.
Could not find swiperefreshlayout.jar (androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0)
```

Answer (score 5):

i fix it by change this for Navigation x5:

androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0

GO to

> .\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\build.gradel
>
> change the version of

```
implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0-beta01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to `android/app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
  implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0-alpha02'
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens#usage-with-react-navigation-without-expo

Comment: ive added this and it is not working ive done every thing as the reactnavigation.org docs but i get error while running app it say's error while reaching the dl.google.maven site

Comment: > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-screens:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find swiperefreshlayout.jar (androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/swiperefreshlayout/swiperefreshlayout/1.0.0/swiperefreshlayout-1.0.0.jar this is the hell error

Comment: please help with this error i think its about navigation version 5

Comment: @amirmarvi did you add `google()` to android/build.gradle file?

Comment: You could check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56561609/8268484

Comment: It did not help me and im still stuck in this issue i dont know whats wrong there.. :_(