# Could not find swiperefreshlayout-1.0.0.aar error when installing new react-native project

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

ok here is step by step what I do:

1- Configure the ANDROID_HOME environment variable. I set sdk path

2- Add platform-tools to environment variable PATH.

3- run npx react-native init MyApp

4- connect my phone, enabling usb debugging

5- downloading and installing gradle 6.5.all

4- downloading and installing sdk build tools 29.0.2

5- start npx react-native start

6- open up another terminal and run npx react-native run-android

this is where app should be installed on my phone but i get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

> Could not find swiperefreshlayout-1.0.0.aar (androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0).
 Searched in the following locations:
     file:/C:/Users/ali/Desktop/react-native/myApp/node_modules/react-native/android/androidx/swiperefreshlayout/swiperefreshlayout/1.0.0/swiperefreshlayout-1.0.0.aar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 59s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

this is my build.gradle file(myApp\android\build.gradle):

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile


project.ext.react = [
enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"


def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false


def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false


def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'


def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate auniversal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
    }
}
signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file('debug.keystore')
        storePassword 'android'
        keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
        keyPassword 'android'
    }
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
        // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
        // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}

// applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
        // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        }

    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
//noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0'
debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
  exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
}

debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
    exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
}

debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
    exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
}

if (enableHermes) {
    def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
    debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
    releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
} else {
    implementation jscFlavor
}
}


task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
from configurations.compile
into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

i've been pulling my hairs out for 3 days. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60463067/could-not-find-swiperefreshlayout-jar-androidx-swiperefreshlayoutswiperefreshl) but in vain

Comment: I am not sure you are using the right commands. First of all you should not have to run 2 terminals with `react-native start` and `react-native run-android` -> it's either one or the other.

And can you check that your device is connected correctly? https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device#2-plug-in-your-device-via-usb-1

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this is obvious to you, but the [react-native masked view library](https://github.com/react-native-masked-view/masked-view) isn’t part of a clean react native project:

> Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_masked-view:generateDebugRFile‘.

My best guess is that you are trying to run `react-native run-android` from a different directory than the one you have just created. The error log indicates you are running `run-android` from `C:/Users/ali/Desktop/react-native/myApp` – can you verify this is the same directory you have installed the clean react-native app into? Running `cd` (Windows) or `pwd` (macOS, Unix, …) in the terminal prints the directory you are currently in.

Again, apologies if this is all clear to you: The following should get started with a fresh project:

1. Run `npx react-native init NewApp` from a directory of your choice, e.g. your desktop. You should now have a folder called `NewApp` on your desktop.
2. Make sure you are in the correct folder (and not a subfolder of or a folder above) `C:/Users/ali/Desktop/NewApp` when starting any react-native tasks like `npx react-native run-android`. Verify by running `cd` if in doubt.
3. Happy coding!

Comment: problem is not with the react-native masked view library. i can fix that. but with swiperefreshlayout-1.0.0.aar. and i run it as you say from the root directory but still get error