# Android Support Library - Failed to Resolve

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library

I am trying to add the following support libraries to my buid.gradle:

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 26

    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {

        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.1.0'
    compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom:imagezoom:1.0.5'
    //Apptentive
    compile 'com.apptentive:apptentive-android:2.1.3@aar'
    //compile 'com.ToxicBakery.viewpager.transforms:view-pager-transforms:1.0.0'

}
```

I am receiving errors stating that each library "Failed to Resolve" followed by each line of code from above. I was hoping to remain current with the latest support libraries for regular support, appcompat, and cardview.

Comment: Make sure you have disabled offline mode.

Comment: can you provide basic instructions?

Comment: Go to Preferences > Gradle and uncheck "Offline work". In Android Studio open the settings and search for offline it will find the Gradle category which contains Offline work. You can disable it there.

Comment: It was actually unchecked already...

Answer (score 9):

To use support libraries starting from version 26.0.0 you need to add Google's Maven repository to your project's build.gradle file as described [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html).

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

What is your buildToolsVersion and compileSdkVersion?

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
}
```

Maybe try updating that in AndroidManifest.xml?  Sometimes they arent compatible and you will have to modify the versions accordingly.

This link might help :[Setting up Gradle for api 26 (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44500176/setting-up-gradle-for-api-26-android)